# Prolog - list contains 2x element X

Tags: list, prolog

Let's assume we have alphabet {x,y} and I want to create a function, which returns true or false, whether the input list contains 2x symbol `x` after each other.

For example `two([x,x,y]).` returns `true`, while `two([x,y,x]).` returns `false`.

This is my function that I have so far:

```
two([Xs]) :- two(Xs, 0).
two([y|Xs], S) :- two(Xs, S).
two([x|Xs], S) :- oneX(Xs, S).
two([], S) :- S=1.

oneX([x|Xs], S) :- S1 is 1, two(Xs, M1).
oneX([y|Xs], S) :- two(Xs, S).
```

I use parameter S to determine, whether there were 2x `x` already (if so, parameter is 1, 0 else). This function however doesn't work as intended and always return `false`. Can you see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only `x`, or is `two([y, y])` sufficient as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *unification* here and thus check if you can unify the first two items of the list with `X`, if not, you recurse on the list:

```
two([x, x|_]).
two([_|T]) :-
    two(T).
```

The first clause thus checks if the first two items of the list are two consecutive `x`s. The second clause recurses on the *tail* of the list to look for another match by moving one step to the right of the list.